# How do I add multiple namespaces in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a situation where I need to use two custom controls in single content page. But when I try to add name spaces of these two controls I get an exception. Is there any solution for that?

```
<ContentPage Title="Settings" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Naseej.Control, clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions" x:Class="Naseej.Page.Setting.SettingList">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```xml
<ContentPage Title="Settings" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
 xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Naseej.Control, clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
 xmlns:anotherControls="Your.Assembly.Path"
 x:Class="Naseej.Page.Setting.SettingList">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try separating the controls

```
<ContentPage Title="Settings" 
 xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
 xmlns:control1="clr-namespace:Naseej.Control;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
 xmlns:control2="clr-namespace:Naseej.Control2;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
 x:Class="Naseej.Page.Setting.SettingList">
```